# QField storing photos inconsistently

Tags: qgis, qfield, photos

When I am taking photos on tablets in QField, inconsistencies exist (while using the same tablet!) in being able to view the photo on desktop.

For example (same tablet, different locations):
[image: tablet 1 oblique layer]

...
[image: tablet 1 transects layer]

Most of the tablets look like this when viewing info:
[image]
...[image]

QGIS info (on Mac, also happens on PC)
[image]

Comment: What are your photo naming rules?